# DRUPAL6 FORM FAPI WITH DRUPAL_RENDER

Tags: drupal-6

i have a drupal form with a element defined like showed above:

```
    'gender' => array(
        '#attributes'    => array(
    '#default_value' => t('Your name'),
             '#option' => $tab
    '#maxlength'     => 255,
        '#required'      => TRUE,
    '#title'         => t('gender'),
    '#type'          => 'select'
    ),
```

Where tab is defined by $tab = {'m','F','mf',fm'}.

And in template file, i ouptput the element by:

in source code i see :
the name of the element becomes genderXXXX where XXXX is a random number whenerver i reload the page.
CAn someone help

Answer (score 0):

The format of your form element is not correct.

To define a select, '#options' must be an array, '#default_value' must be the key of your options, '#attributes' is used to define additional HTML attributes, '#maxlength' is used by textfield and password etc..

You'd better have a look at the api of form: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/6#select

Here is a simple example:

```
$tab = array('m', 'F', 'mf', 'fm');
$form['gender'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('gender'),
    '#default_value' => 0, // default value will be m
    '#options' => $tab,
    '#size' => 255,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'gender_select')       
);
```